# Can't install Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I can't install or use Gradle on Ubuntu 22.04

I've downloaded Gradle, unzipped it into /opt/gradle and used 'export PATH=$PATH:/opt/gradle/gradle-8.0.2/bin' yet when I run 'gradle -v' in the terminal I get:
Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.

I have no idea how to fix this error.

Comment: you can check if everything correct and path updated: echo $PATH

Answer (score 1):

Try stopping Gradle daemons, which usually solves this problem:

```
gradle --stop
rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches
gradle
```

A better way to install it is via the package manager:

```
sudo apt install gradle
```

Another option is to install the Gradle wrapper into your project. If you have a working version from the package manager:

```
cd ~/my-project
gradle wrapper
./gradlew
```

If you don’t have any working Gradle version, download it from https://github.com/gradle/gradle/releases

```
unzip gradle-xxx.zip
cd gradle-xxx
cp gradlew ~/my-project
cp gradlew.bat ~/my-project
cp -r gradle ~/my-project
cd ~/my-project
./gradlew
```